# How do I define recursive types in XSD?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I'm fighting with XSD at the moment and it's kind of winning. I'm trying to define a type as follows:

```
 <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Condition1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Operator" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SourceTableValue" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ValueToCompareTo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element type="logicalOperator" name ="AND" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                  <xs:element type="logicalOperator" name ="OR" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                  <xs:element type="logicalOperator" name ="NOT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Condition2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Operator" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SourceTableValue" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ValueToCompareTo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element type="logicalOperator" name ="AND" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                  <xs:element type="logicalOperator" name ="OR" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                  <xs:element type="logicalOperator" name ="NOT" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
....
```

However, this gives me an error, Visual Studio underlines  **xs:element type="logicalOperator"** and says "Namespace '' is not available to be referenced in this schema". 
Then, when I'm trying to reference the type "logicalOperator" later in the schema I'm getting an error "type logicalOperator is not declared". 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema is too mangled for a precise diagnostic; assuming that the XML namespace declarations are just the one that you've shown, then by simply adding `xmlns="http://www.abc.com/"` to your **<xs:schema>** element you should be able to reference the content you define in the same schema file or a different schema file with the same target namespace using names without a prefix.

This snippet:

```
<xs:element type="logicalOperator" .../>
```

is trying to lookup a `logicalOperator` type that has no namespace - sometimes printed as `{}logicalOperator`

By adding the xmlns as indicated above, then the same becomes `{http://www.abc.com/}logicalOperator`

To be fair, XSD is not the only one fighting you here; [XML Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/), too :)...

Comment: You're right. But can you help? An example of a simple xsd with a custom recursive type defined in it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working. Thanks Petru.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:abc="http://www.abc.com/">  
   <xs:complexType  name="logicalOperator">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Condition1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Operator" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SourceTableValue" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ValueToCompareTo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element type="abc:logicalOperator" name ="AND" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element type="abc:logicalOperator" name ="OR" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element type="abc:logicalOperator" name ="NOT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Condition2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Operator" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SourceTableValue" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ValueToCompareTo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element type="abc:logicalOperator" name ="AND" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element type="abc:logicalOperator" name ="OR" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element type="abc:logicalOperator" name ="NOT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```